# Entity Framework4, to see generated query?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework4 (Code First).

and I want to see the generated query.

I found this code in Stackoverflow.

```
var trace = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)result).ToTraceString();
```

but this is not working, the error message say,

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[PJ.Mysql.Entities.Order]' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery'.
```

My code is,

```
[HttpGet]
public void test()
{
    EFOrdersRepository ordersRepository = new EFOrdersRepository();
    var query = ordersRepository.Orders;

    var result = from x in query
         where x.orderid == 99008326
         select x;

    var trace = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)result).ToTraceString(); //it does not work

    Response.Write(trace);
}
```

EFOrdersRepository.cs

```
 public class EFOrdersRepository
{
private EFMysqlContext context = new EFMysqlContext();

public IQueryable<Order> Orders
{
    get { return context.orders; }
}
}
```

EFMysqlContext.cs

```
class EFMysqlContext : DbContext
{
     public DbSet<Order> orders { get; set; }
}
```

I really want to solve this problem =3, anybody knows ?

Comment: I strongly recommend you look at EF Profiler: http://efprof.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [mini-profiler](http://miniprofiler.com/) which allows you to trace SQL queries. And here's a [nice blog post](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/07/28/using-the-asp-net-mvc-mini-profiler-with-lightspeed/) detailing its setup.

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
var trace = result.ToString();
```

Comment: I mean, the same functionality in `DbQuery` is achieved using `ToString()`